# Getting RGB or other colour values for Smart Master

Tags: python, openxml, python-pptx

With [md2pptx](https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx) the user generally supplies colours as RGB values. I'd like an alternative where they can use eg `ACCENT_1` or whatever the template presentation calls it. Motivation: You probably don't know the RGB value of a colour in a template you're handed.

Is there a programmatic method - either in python-pptx - or spelunking in the XML to retrieve the colours' RGB values, along with their names? I don't mean "pale violet"; I do mean eg "ACCENT_1".

If not I suppose I could be confecting XML that uses these names. Might that be a better idea anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you can specify an RGB color you can also specify a so-called "theme" or sometimes called a "scheme" color.

Like:

```
from docx.enum.dml import MSO_THEME_COLOR

font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR.ACCENT_2
```

Comment: Right. But in my case I'm going deeper: Manipulating the XML more than python-pptx allows me to do.

Example: Adding lines round all the cells in a table. I've got it working for RGB values for such lines. I think I understand the XML now in the scheme. Apart from which is the current theme. In my template I seem to have two. It does involve parsing at least one more XML file in the zip - which isn't fun.

Comment: Actually the scheme colour elements have distinct element names. So long as I inject these instead of sRGBClr elements I should be OK. After all, all I want is for the user to be able to specify eg "ACCENT_1" and my code doesn't actually need to know the RGB value that is equivalent.